# How to get reticulate to recognize my miniconda python and my environments?

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I am relatively new to python and would like to install it the "right" way (of which, of course, there are many) to use both natively and with R through reticulate.

Here's what I have done so far:

- I reinstalled MacOS Catalina from scratch and installed Miniconda with homebrew.
- Through miniconda, I have updated to python 3.8.5.
- Then, I installed reticulate in R (R version 4.0.2., RStudio version 1.3.1056). When reticulate asked me whether I wanted to install miniconda, I declined (since it was already installed.
- I aliased python3 with python in my zsh terminal.

This is where the trouble started. I couldn't (and can't) get reticulate to recognize my python installation or, if I can get reticulate to recognize it, I can't get it to recognize my python environment.

As advised [elsewhere](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/498), I changed my `RETICULATE_PYTHON` to `/usr/local/bin/python3`, which actually matches one of my python installations. Now I get the error `Error: could not find a Python environment for /usr/local/bin/python3`

I also tried setting my path to my miniconda python, which is located somewhere in `/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/`. Or more specifically, as obtained by `type -a python python3`, in `/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/python3`. Unfortunately, once I changed the reticulate directory to the miniconda version, `type` no longer returns `/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/python3`, for reasons that I don't understand.

When I now run `type -a python python3`, I receive the following output:

```
python is an alias for python3
python is /usr/bin/python
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
```

I don't know what happened to my miniconda installation (which still seems to work fine, when I run `conda --version`, I receive `conda 4.8.3`).

So to summarize the status quo:

- Running python from the terminal works (both interactive and to execute a py file)
- Reticulate recognizes the path I set in `RETICULATE_PYTHON`
- My miniconda no longer appears when I run `type -a python python3`
- Most importantly: reticulate does not recognize my environment even though I have created an environment with miniconda in the terminal and another environment in Rstudio using `reticulate::conda_create()` and I have also made sure to activate them.

So my question is, how can I get reticulate to

1. Recognize my miniconda python
2. Recognize the various environments that I create with conda (both inside and outside of R)